# node_delete() does not trigger the "deleting content" Rule?

Tags: nodes

Due to certain requirements, we are developing a custom module to handle node creation and deletion, using `node_save()` and `node_delete()` respectively. However when we add a Rule with the Rules module to perform certain tasks with the events "After saving new content" and "After deleting content", the event "After saving new content" is triggered with `node_save()` without problem, but the event "After deleting content" is never triggered at all with `node_delete()`. Anyone has any idea what could be going wrong here? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short inspection of rules code showed that it should be triggered after node delete:

```
function rules_entity_delete($entity, $type) {
  switch ($type) {
  ...
    case 'node':
      rules_invoke_event('node_delete--' . $entity->type, $entity);
      rules_invoke_event('node_delete', $entity);
      break;
  ...
```

(from events.inc)

Have you tried turning on rules debug to see what is happening? Go to *admin/config/workflow/rules/settings* and turn on *Show debug information* to *Always*.

Maybe the event *is* being invoked, but some of your condition is incorrect and it appears that nothing is happening.